# Invalid Layer Save Flag - only ALL_SAVE_FLAGS is allowed android API 28+

Tags: android, canvas

Estou tendo este problema depois de alterar a `targetSdkVersion` de **25** para **28**, estou tendo que realizar esta alteração pois é necessário este sdk para publicar na loja do google.

A `exception` gerada:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Layer Save Flag - only ALL_SAVE_FLAGS is allowed
        at android.graphics.Canvas.checkValidSaveFlags(Canvas.java:442)
        at android.graphics.Canvas.saveLayer(Canvas.java:519)
        at com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.view.BezelImageView.onDraw(BezelImageView.java:209)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22213)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21089)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21944)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4180)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21080)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21944)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4180)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21080)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21944)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4180)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21080)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21944)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4419)
        at android.widget.ListView.drawChild(ListView.java:3613)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4180)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2668)
        at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3608)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22216)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4369)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21089)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21944)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4180)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22216)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21089)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21944)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4419)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1379)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4180)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21080)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4403)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4376)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21049)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4403)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4376)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21049)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4403)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4376)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21049)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4403)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4376)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21049)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4403)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4376)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21049)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:559)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:565)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4058)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3785)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1888)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8122)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
2020-04-13 13:16:46.209 31317-31317/br.com.desen.amauditores E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7464)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:955)
```

Observei que na classe `BezelImageView.java` existe uma chamada para saveLayer:

```
cacheCanvas.saveLayer(mBoundsF, mMaskedPaint,
                        Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG | Canvas.FULL_COLOR_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
```

Porém esta classe nao pode ser alterada para deixar como default `ALL_SAVE_FLAGS`

Alguém ja passou por isso e poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Se a sua dúvida tiver sido respondida, por favor, aceite a resposta. Veja mais detalhes em [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079)

Answer (score 0):

Você está utilizando uma versão desatualizada do `com.mikepenz.materialdrawer`. Dando uma pesquisada no GitHub deles, encontrei esse [issue](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/2519) onde o mantenedor do repositório diz

> Essas *flags* não são mais aplicadas em versões recentes.
>
> Por favor, atualize o **MaterialDrawer**.

Veja as [versões disponíveis](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/releases) e atualize o seu `gradle` de acordo.

Siga o [guia de migração](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/MIGRATION.md) passo a passo. Veja a sua versão atual e compare com uma mais recente do que ela para saber o que mudou. O guia de migração possui diversos exemplos do tipo "renomeie X para Y".

Com isso, você conseguirá chegar à uma versão que não tenha esse problema (aparentemente, a versão mais antiga sem esse problema é a `v6.0.9`). Recomendo fortemente fazer o passo a passo até a versão **mais recente** (`v8.0.0` no guia de migração) para corrigir possíveis bugs que você ainda não percebeu e evitar novos problemas de migração por ter uma versão tão antiga.

Comment: Estou utilizando uma versão muito antiga: compile('com.mikepenz.materialdrawer:library:2.9.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
}
Quanto tento migrar para uma versao mais recente: 
compile group: 'com.mikepenz', name: 'materialdrawer', version: '8.0.1'
me proporciona outro erro:
C:\Users\hcs01\.android\build-cache\bb3a14d3dfbcfbe9711ebec71497bfb1b45d6b70\output\res\font\materialdrawerfont_font_v5_0_0.ttf: Error: The file name must end with .xml

Comment: Dê uma olhada no guia de migração, que coloquei na resposta. Migre de uma versão para outra, não da `2.9.8` para a `8.0.1`. Ao migrar, faça um *clear build* do seu projeto, leia no guia o que precisará mudar em código e veja se ocorre algum erro. Faça isso progressivamente até chegar na versão desejada.

Comment: Ok, vou serguir o guia de migração, obrigado.